# bulk update strongly typed dataset?

Tags: .net, asp.net

is it possible to do a batch update in a strongly typed data set?  UpdateBatchSize does not seem to be an option once you create a strongly typed dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to add this property to the DataAdapter? Extend the autogenerated Adapter class with a Property UpdateBatchSize, for example(<strike>not tested yet</strike>):

```
Namespace DataSet1TableAdapters
    Partial Public Class AddressTableAdapter
        Public Property UpdateBatchSize() As Integer
            Get
                Return Me.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                Me.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize = value
                If value <> 1 Then
                    Me.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None
                    Me.Adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None
                    Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None
                Else
                    Me.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord
                    Me.Adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord
                    Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Have a look into the autogenerated `designer.cs/vb` for the names of the Namespace and the partial adapter-classes you want to extend with the bulk-update-functionality and put them into a file with the same name as the Dataset but without `designer`. If you cannot follow me, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171896%28VS.80%29.aspx).

C#

```
namespace DataSet1TableAdapters
{
    public partial class AddressTableAdapter
    {
        public int UpdateBatchSize {
            get { return this.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize; }
            set {
                this.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize = value;
                if (value != 1) {
                    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                    this.Adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                    this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                } else {
                    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
                    this.Adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
                    this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>If that works</strike> , it only works the way i described, because you cannot change the autogenerated file directly, because it will be regenerated automatically on changes.

**Edit**: After reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx) i changed the code above to set the `UpdatedRowSource` property accordingly.

Tested with following code:

```
Dim stopWatch As New Stopwatch
Dim da As New DataSet1TableAdapters.AddressTableAdapter
Dim tblAllAdresses As New DataSet1.AddressDataTable
Dim tsBS1, tsBS0 As TimeSpan

da.Fill(tblAllAdresses)

da.UpdateBatchSize = 1
For Each adrr As DataSet1.AddressRow In tblAllAdresses
    adrr.ModifiedDate = Date.Now
Next
stopWatch.Start()
Dim addressesChanged As Int32 = da.Update(tblAllAdresses)
stopWatch.Stop()
tsBS1 = stopWatch.Elapsed

da.UpdateBatchSize = 0 '0 means maximum server can handle'
For Each adrr As DataSet1.AddressRow In tblAllAdresses
    adrr.ModifiedDate = Date.Now
Next
stopWatch.Restart()
addressesChanged = da.Update(tblAllAdresses)
stopWatch.Stop()
tsBS0 = stopWatch.Elapsed

Console.WriteLine("tsBS1: " & tsBS1.Minutes & ":" & tsBS1.Seconds & ":" & tsBS1.Milliseconds) '12 seconds'
Console.WriteLine("tsBS0: " & tsBS0.Minutes & ":" & tsBS0.Seconds & ":" & tsBS0.Milliseconds) '9 seconds(on localhost!)'
```

Comment: I don't seem to have UpdateBatchSize on my adapters. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: @Carlos: Yes, i've extended the auto-generated TableAdapter with the property UpdateBatchSize. I have decribed above how it works.

Comment: @Tim: I don't understand. Doesn't your code simply wrap a member called UpdateBatchSize?

Comment: @Carlos: Are we talking about the same issue, are you trying to set the UpdateBatchSize in a strong type dataset with auto-generated TableAdapters(from VS-Dataset Designer)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't see the inner adapters having this property, so how are you setting it?

Comment: @Carlos: VS generates a designer.cs/vb-file under your dataset. You cannot change it directly because it will be regenerated on changes. If you look at this file you'll see what classes VS has generated. You have to create a file with the same name but without the trailing 'designer'. Then you can extend the functionality of these classes(f.e. the TableAdapters) by creating partial classes with the same name and add the property above to this class. Use the same NameSpace as in designer-file(f.e. DataSet1TableAdapters).
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171896%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Tim: Another question... when does it actually send the batch of updates? Is there a timeout?